# Project to Project Reference does not generate right nuget dependency when using GeneratePackageOnBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I have 3 projects in my solution.
As part of the build process in TFS I generate 3 NuGet pacakges by using the GeneratePackageOnBuild property in my project file (new csproj for VS 2017).

```
Project1
Project2
Project3
  |_ ProjectReference Project1.csproj
  |_ ProjectReference Project2.csproj
```

I have 2 different builds. One for preview and another one for final builds.
When using the one for preview I add `-preview-<BuildId>` to all projects.
The generated NuGet packages are successfully generated with this version. But the package dependencies are generated without the preview suffix.

How can I tell MSBuild to generate the dependencies with the right version?

**UPDATE:**
It seems like the nuspec files that are generated at build time are created based on `project.assets.json` I have conditional properties in project imports for versioning and it seems that when `project.assets.json` is generated the variables for conditions don't exist for referenced projects and generating the wrong dependency version which then flows into the automatically generated nuspec file for the package.